# Can I stop the F7 key from launching the default email application in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hotkeys

Since I changed to Windows 10, every time I press <kbd>F7</kbd> a new window of Outlook is launched.

I tried to override this behavior in applications (*Word, Excel, Visual Studio*) but any of them seem to detect the <kbd>F7</kbd> input event.

Why is <kbd>F7</kbd> launching the e-mail app, and how can I stop it?

Also, I searched google all around and couldn't find an answer.

Comment: It is probably your keyboard. Some deafult to F-keys, some to FN-keys.

Comment: F1-F12 are all ok, except for F7. My keyboard is a Kinesis Advantage Pro with default config.

Comment: So it is a programmable keyboard. Check your settings. Try to change the behaviuor for F7 and see what will happen.

Comment: [User Manual](http://www.kinesis-ergo.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/kinesis_advantage_user_manual.pdf)

Comment: I can't assign a different keycode to a key. I can only remap existent keycodes. The problem is the F7 and F8 keys do not input their usual keycode. Instead, they return a keycode larger than a byte, which can not be mapped using SharpKeys, or KeyTweak, or KeyMapper =/

Answer (score 0):

Using [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/), you can rewrite `F7` to be another shortcut or simply disable it using this line of code:

Map `F7` to `Escape`: `F7::Escape`

Disable `F7`: `F7::`